# How to Download the jsp table as excel file using jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using spring with MVC also jsp page for presenting. I have requirement of allowing end user to download the table which is shown in jsp as excel sheet. The tables contain i am rendering through using  the model map attribute as shown below.

```
<div id="hotel_user">
<table width="98%" style="border:5px solid #999999" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CFD7E8">
<tr style="background-color:#72E076">
  <td width="auto" height="27" align="center">Date</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td width="0%" height="27" align="center" class="row2"><b>${aff.date_string}</b></td>
 <td width="auto" height="27" align="center"><b>${aff.no_of_posted} </b></td>
 <td width="auto" height="27" align="center"><b>${aff.no_of_listed}</b> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div> 
  <input type="button" id="download" value="Download As Excell">
```

on click of button the table data should be downloaded as excel.
i have seen and tried to implement the code, it downlaod but conatin null vale in excel sheet.
following below link i have implemented.
    http://jsfiddle.net/n9XRx/

i have used in jquery as:

```
 $("#download").click(function() {  
 var hotel_user = $('#hotel_user').html();    
 window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#hotel_user').html());
});
```

Any suggestion wat i am making mistake.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to convert the data in html table into an excel document first. Start with [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jexcelapi/)
You'll have to generate the document on server side and then you'll be able to initiate proper download.